# Plot 2D in line graph for android using eclipse

Tags: plot

im looking for a working source code about plotting 2D to line graph using java.

So far I've been try AndroidPlot but I had so many error, for example "Unfortunately apps is stop" .

Im tired and sick with Eclipse because user must concern about its compatible version of everything.

So, I really need a complete tutorial for plotting 2D to line graph, which works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some Android plotting libraries and stopped at Android Plot. It is really good, but indeed a bit hard to understand how the sample code works.

[Tutorials and docs of AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/docs/) are sufficient to be able to use it. However, I wasted 5 hours to create plotting engine for my app. I recommend you to study sample code in the docs and try to understand how it works. What is important is that when the plot is redrawn, you need to replace values in the set, but not add new values.

I used following strategy to deploy this library: I copied sample code to my project and replaced small pieces of code there and looked what happens.

UPDATE: Also take a look at [this video in youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NgZewUzC3s). It explains very well what to do.